# Extract Instagram Followers Number With JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

It used to be possible to use `?__a=1` at the end of an Instagram profile URL to get the profile data in JSON format and easily extract information from there. When I try now, all I get is this:

`for (;;);{"redirect":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/pubgm_silvanus\/"}`

If I use this:

`https://www.instagram.com/pubgm_silvanus?__a=1`

Are you getting the same? Is there any other easy way to extract the follower number (in this case `11`) with JavaScript?

Here is the code I am using:

````
# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.
import time

import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\Crawling\pythonProject1\driver\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)#, options=options)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Account', 'Followers'])


def login(username, password):
    driver.get("http://www.instagram.com")

    # bypass cookie consent
    accept = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[1]"))).click()

    # target username
    uname = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
    pwd = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")))

    # enter username and password
    uname.clear()
    uname.send_keys(username)
    pwd.clear()
    pwd.send_keys(password)


    time.sleep(5)
    # target the login button and click it
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

    time.sleep(5)
    alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not now")]'))).click()
    alert2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not '
                                                                                   'Now")]'))).click()

    # We are logged in!

    return 0


def get_accounts_list():
    accounts_list = []
    with open("./accounts.txt") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        account = line.strip() + "?__a=1"
        accounts_list.append(account)
    return accounts_list


def create_data_frame(accounts_list):
    for account in accounts_list:
        try:
            driver.get(account)
            page_source = driver.page_source
            number_of_followers = page_source.split('"edge_followed_by":{"count":')[1].split('}')[0]
            df1.loc[len(df1)] = [account.split("?__a=1")[0], number_of_followers]
            df1.to_csv("accounts.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
            print(account.split("?__a=1")[0], number_of_followers)
        except Exception as err:
            print(account)
            print("Error, I had to skip this account")
            continue
    return 1


def launcher(message):
    print(message)
    # Credentials.
    username = ""  # edit this
    password = ""  # and this
    try:
        login(username, password)
    except BaseException as login_err:
        print("Error occurred while trying to log in:", login_err)
    
    accounts_list = get_accounts_list()
    if create_data_frame(accounts_list):
        print("Done.")
        df1.to_csv("accounts.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
        driver.close()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # specify the path to chromedriver.exe (download and save on your computer)
    # open the webpage
    launcher('Booting up....')```
````

Comment: Post your code. The link works in browser, so its probably just a case of missing some headers.

Answer (score 0):

This link you provided does show all the profile data in JSON format.

To get follower number, use this path
`graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count`

[image: Path]

Using fetch API you can fetch the JSON and put it in array.

Comment: Hmm, so strange. I added the code now. That is what I have been using for thousands of accounts for a few weeks now, and I did not change anything in the code, but now it is suddenly not working no matter what account or IP I use

Comment: I'm not sure why this happened to you. Perhaps they are blocking requests coming from you in some way because of fetching too much data too many times.